# How was Crowley able to return to his vessel after being exorcised?

Tags: supernatural

Perhaps I am missing something here but In the latest episode of Supernatural (S11E18) Crowley enters Castiels vessel in an attempt to convince him to expel Lucifer. However, Lucifer attacks Crowley and he asks for Sam and Deans help. Sam performs an exorcism in order to save Crowley. In every previous exorcism, the demon which has been exorcised is forced to return to hell so how did Crowley manage to avoid this and return straight to his vessel?

Comment: Dane good question...however it was several days, a nights sleep, and a couple of fish tacos cool water and his friend carried him from where he layed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "The Phantom Traveler," it was established that there are two parts to an exorcism: expelling the demon from the vessel, and then sending the demon back to hell. Sam most likely only performed half the exorcism.